# Python - Cumulatively Count by Unique ID in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, unique

I am having some difficulty with a pretty basic data manipulation problem in Python.  I have data that looks like the following:

```
Col1
A
A
A
B
B
C
C
C
D
```

I want to be able to cumulatively count by the unique values of Col1.  My ideal output would look like this:

```
Col1 Col2
A    1
A    1
A    1
B    2
B    2
C    3
C    3
C    3
D    4
```

I have been searching around StackOverflow, but have been unable to find exactly the solution I'm looking for.  A lot of the solutions I have found involve aggregating the data using the groupby function, but that's not what I want - I want to preserve the structure of the data.  Can someone help me figure this out?

Any help would be appreciated!  Thank you!

Comment: `df['Col1'].factorize()[0] + 1`.

Comment: You're welcome. Answer is not necessary. this is most likely a duplicate. You can search SO for `factorize` or categorize.